# Regular expression not operator on a pallern

Tags: regex, text-parsing

I have a string like the following

`this <b>is <i>a sample</i> string</b> with multiple <b>words and some</b> keywords <b>and partially formatted</b> text.`

I need to get the between `<b> and </b>` where no nested `<i> </i>` tags. 
That is I need  "words and some" as first match and "and partially formatted" as second match.

Comment: Using regular expressions on irregularly formatted text is almost _always_ a bad idea :-) You may be better of getting _all_ bold sections then simply discarding those with italics tags within them.

Comment: since you want to search based on <b> and </b> and <i> </i> why not use the String APi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regular expression like this :

```
<b>(?![^}]*(<i>|<\/i>))([^}]+?)<\/b>
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/zM1zO6

you will get the results in the second match group

Comment: For this string  `this <b>is <i>a sample</i> string</b> with multiple <b>words <u>and</u> some</b> keywords <b>and partially formatted</b> text.` when I am using `<b>(?![^}]*(<u>|<\/u>))([^}]+?)<\/b>` then it is getting only one match. this time `<i>...</i>` need to be included